# What is the fastest posible way to comunicate to a server on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, latency, websocket, lag

I need to communicate via WebSockes and normal HTTP. I am trying to save some microseconds.
I have already done:

1. I got an instance at the same Amazon EC2 zone. The ping is 1 millisecond.
2. I have translated the application from Perl to Julia. It is a very simple WebSockets application. Is it worth translating to C?

I am using Window Server. Would Linux be faster? I already have no problem with bandwidth. What does generally save some microseconds on network communication setups?

Comment: The fastest way to communicate is to be close physically. As such, consider a globally distributed CDN for your HTTP requests like CloudFront or CloudFlare.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, if latencies in the microsecond range are a problem, you should not be using AWS.  You need a computer on the same local network as your server.